# Database Isolation: writing while using "Read Uncommitted" level

Tags: sql, database, multithreading, locking, isolation-level

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) characterizes the isolation levels in databases according to the duration for which write-, read-, and range-locks are held.  In particular, the isolation level "Read Uncommitted" holds write-locks only for the duration of each relevant statement.  However, several other references state that transactions operating at this level of isolation should have read-only access, which, of course, does not require a write-lock at all.

If it is permissible for a transaction with "Read Uncommitted" isolation to make writes, why is read-only access recommended for these transactions?

Comment: 'Read uncommitted' ignores any write locks held. Attempting to write will take write locks. Other writers will be blocked. I don't see a real question here. You use the 'Read uncommitted'transaction isolation level when you want "...to read rows that have been modified by other transactions but not yet committed."

Comment: Btw: not every DBMS supports read uncommited.